# How does ftpd service access the FTP protocol to understand how to transfer files?

Tags: ftp, protocols

This question applies not only to the FTP protocol, but also to other protocols in general.

We call FTP a protocol, but speaking literally, FTP has a source code. When an ftpd service is running on a server, how does this service access and make use of the FTP source code? Is the source code embedded into the ftpd service?

Many thanks and cheers.

Comment: Every daemon or binary on Linux is compiled from source but don't use it while running. When running FTPD you use the binary not the source code. Even if you want to use source code, you should be able to download & modify it, but before recompiling it as a binary you will not be able to use it.

Comment: *speaking literally, FTP has a source code* No. It has a specification/mode of operation each FTP server and client implement.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing up FTP and `ftp`.

- [FTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) translates to "File Transfer Protocol". It was introduced first
  1971, current version is defined in
  [RFC959](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc959). It's part of the [TCP/IP protocol suite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite).
- [ftp](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ftp/netkit-ftp.1) is a command-line FTP client, i.e. an application that connects to an FTP server using TCP ports 20 and 21 to transfer files using FTP protocol. `get` and `put` are examples of available functions / capabilities. There are several FTP clients with command-line or graphical interfaces.

Comment: LOL you're right, fixed :-D And thx for reminding about die.net - I corrected it now to Debian man pages :-)

Answer (score 0):

> We call FTP a protocol, but speaking literally, FTP has a source code

No. FTP is a protocol.

A FTP client or a FTP server *implementation* are programs that have source code.

So, your question really has it backwards; the program *implements* the protocol.

> Is the source code embedded into the ftpd service?

Usually not. This really boils down to understanding what source code is in relation to an executable program. But you could write an FTP server which includes its own source code. That would serve no special purpose, though.